# linear combination of polynomial equal to zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I have a trouble with the following question.

Let $p,q \in K[x]$. There are polynomials $a(x),b(X) \in K[x]$ with $\deg(a) < \deg(q)$ and $\deg(b) < \deg(p)$ such that 
$$a(x)p(x) + b(x)q(x) =  0$$ if and only if $\gcd(p,q) \neq 1$.

For the $(\implies)$, I have tried assuming that $\gcd(p,q) = 1$, then I write $$1 = rp + sq$$ but I can not get a contradiction.

As for $(\Longleftarrow)$ is a bit straightforward: If $d = \gcd(p,q)$ then $\deg(d) > 0$ by assumption. Therefore $p = db$ and $q = da$ for some polynomials $a,b$. So we have $ ap = a(db) = b (da) = bq$; that is $ap - bq = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\implies)$ Suppose $\gcd \{p,q\} = 1$. Then there exists $r(x), s(x) \in K[x]$ such that $$r(x)p(x) + s(x)q(x) = 1$$

As $a(x)p(x) = -b(x)q(x)$ then $$\begin{align}-r(x)b(x)q(x) + s(x)a(x)q(x) &= a(x) \implies q(x)[s(x)a(x) - r(x)b(x)] = a(x) \\&\implies \deg a(x) = \deg q (x) + \deg [s(x)a(x) - r(x)b(x)] \geq \deg q(x) \end{align}$$

generates an absurd. (Here we assume that $K[x]$ is a ring).